# What can be a case of VkCmdPipelineBarrier() not transitioning image layout

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I'm trying to extract images from swapchain and convert them so I can create a video out of them.

I'm trying to transition an image layout using a one-time submission command buffer. After submitting a command buffer to a queue, I get warnings and errors from validation layers saying that image layouts are wrongly formatted, but I have clearly set a pipeline barrier using all the right parameters.

This happens even when I transition texture layouts for my objects, but everything works fine even with those warnings. I cant read extracted image's contents because of this error.

What can be a cause of this? Here is how I convert layouts:

```
VkCommandBuffer cmdBuffer = commandBuffer == VK_NULL_HANDLE ? 
                            CommandBufferHandler::createOneTimeUsageBuffer(commandPool, device) : commandBuffer;
VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
VkPipelineStageFlags sourceStage = {};
VkPipelineStageFlags dstStage = {};

barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
barrier.oldLayout = oldLayout;
barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
barrier.image = image;
barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = mipLevels;
barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

if (newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;

    if (hasStencilComponent(format)) {
        barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask |= VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_STENCIL_BIT;
    }
}
else {
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
}

if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;

    sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

    sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

    sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
    sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
}
else {
    throw std::invalid_argument("unsupported layout transition!");
}

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmdBuffer, sourceStage, dstStage, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);

if (commandBuffer == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
    CommandBufferHandler::endOneTimeUsageBuffer(cmdBuffer, queue, commandPool, device);
}
```

And here is how I capture an image:

```
VkImageCreateInfo screenshotCreateInfo;
VkImage srcImage = images[activeImageSwapchainId];
VkDeviceMemory dstImageMemory;
VkImage dstImage = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

if (supportsBlit) {
    VkCommandBuffer cmdBuffer = CommandBufferHandler::createOneTimeUsageBuffer(
        mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(), mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice());

    Util::createImage(sizeX, sizeY, 1, VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT,
        &dstImage, &dstImageMemory, mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getPhysicalDeviceMemoryPropertiesPTR());

    Util::transitionImageLayout(dstImage,
        VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
        mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
        1,
        cmdBuffer);

    Util::transitionImageLayout(srcImage,
        VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
        mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
        1,
        cmdBuffer);


    VkOffset3D offsets{};
    offsets.x = swapExtent.width;
    offsets.y = swapExtent.height;
    offsets.z = 1;

    VkImageBlit blit{};
    blit.srcSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    blit.srcSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    blit.dstSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    blit.dstSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    blit.srcOffsets[1] = offsets;
    blit.dstOffsets[1] = offsets;

    vkCmdBlitImage(cmdBuffer,
        srcImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
        dstImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
        1, &blit, VK_FILTER_NEAREST);

    Util::transitionImageLayout(dstImage, VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL,
        mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
        1,
        cmdBuffer);

    Util::transitionImageLayout(srcImage, VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
        mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
        mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
        1,
        cmdBuffer);

    CommandBufferHandler::endOneTimeUsageBuffer(cmdBuffer, mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
        mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(), mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice());

    VkImageSubresource subresource{ VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0 };
    VkSubresourceLayout subresourceLayout;
    vkGetImageSubresourceLayout(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImage, &subresource, &subresourceLayout);

    const char *data = nullptr;
    vkMapMemory(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImageMemory, 0, VK_WHOLE_SIZE, 0, (void**)&data);
    data += subresourceLayout.offset;

    std::ofstream file(filePath, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    file << "P6\n" << swapExtent.width << "\n" << swapExtent.height << "\n" << 255 << "\n";     //File header

    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < swapExtent.height; ++y) {
        unsigned int *row = (unsigned int*)data;

        for (uint32_t x = 0; x < swapExtent.width; ++x) {
            file.write((char*)row, 3);
            row++;
        }

        data += subresourceLayout.rowPitch;
    }

    file.close();

    std::cout << "Screenshot saved to: " << filePath << std::endl;

    vkUnmapMemory(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImageMemory);
    vkFreeMemory(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImageMemory, nullptr);
    vkDestroyImage(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImage, nullptr);
}
else {
    assert(0 && "Swapchain error: Your device does not support image blitting. Cannot save image. Will be patched.");
    return;
}
```

Warnings are like on the image below. All other warnings come from my image layout not being transitioned.

[image: Mip levels are 0-9]

When I use blit, I get this error. I'm creating `dstImage` with `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` format.

[image]

Comment: What are the "warnings and errors from validation"?

Comment: @NicolBolas Question edited so it contains warning text.

Comment: You don't have to use blit if the dimensions are the same. The error message text was changed few months back, which indicates you are using obsolete SDK. The reported mip level does not seem to match (should probably be 0), as well as the original layout is weird. Find to which image the reported pointer belongs. Also which command actually trigerred the error. If you have prior validation errors, fix those first.

Comment: @krOoze I updated my SDK. MipLevel warning isn't the problem as it seems, layout does get transitioned. Now new error appears saying that dstImage format doesn't have `VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_BLIT_DST` enabled. Question is updated.

Comment: @Riki Your code says `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` but you write `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`. Nevertheles `BLIT` feature should be supported for both by guaranteed caps. Can you verify the support by running `vulkaninfo`?

Comment: PS: "mip level 8" is still weird. And `SHADER_READ_ONLY` comes out of nowhere. Still seems like the error is referring to a completely different image than the `dstImage`...  Make sure we are talking about the correct image. Make sure it is created with only one mip level.

Comment: @krOoze Fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Warnings that I was getting aren't related to trying to extract an image. They were from trying to create texture mipmaps for my object. That is something I didn't fix.

What I fixed was this blitting error. I just avoided using it, and used `vkCmdCopyImage()` instead. Here is how:

```
void Swapchain::saveScreenshot(std::string filePath) {
    VkImageCreateInfo screenshotCreateInfo;
    VkImage srcImage = images[activeImageSwapchainId];
    VkDeviceMemory dstImageMemory;
    VkImage dstImage = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    if (supportsBlit) {
        VkCommandBuffer cmdBuffer = CommandBufferHandler::createOneTimeUsageBuffer(
            mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(), mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice());

        Util::createImage(sizeX, sizeY, 1, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
            VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT,
            &dstImage, &dstImageMemory, mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getPhysicalDeviceMemoryPropertiesPTR());

        //NOVU Sliku prebacujemo u transfer destination
        Util::transitionImageLayout(dstImage,
            VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
            mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
            1,
            cmdBuffer);

        //Staru sliku prebacujemo iz prezentacije u transfer source
        Util::transitionImageLayout(srcImage,
            VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
            mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
            1,
            cmdBuffer);

        VkExtent3D extent = { swapExtent.width, swapExtent.height, 1 };
        VkOffset3D offsets{};
        offsets.x = 0;
        offsets.y = 0;
        offsets.z = 0;

        VkImageSubresourceLayers layers{};
        layers.mipLevel = 0;
        layers.layerCount = 1;
        layers.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        layers.baseArrayLayer = 0;

        VkImageCopy regions{};
        regions.dstOffset = offsets;
        regions.extent = extent;
        regions.srcOffset = offsets;
        regions.srcSubresource = layers;
        regions.dstSubresource = layers;

        vkCmdCopyImage(cmdBuffer,
            srcImage,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
            dstImage,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
            1,
            &regions);

        Util::transitionImageLayout(dstImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL,
            mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
            1,
            cmdBuffer);

        Util::transitionImageLayout(srcImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
            mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
            mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(),
            1,
            cmdBuffer);

        CommandBufferHandler::endOneTimeUsageBuffer(cmdBuffer, mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices()->getQueue(),
            mainWindow->getCommandHandler()->getCommandPool(), mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice());

        unsigned char *data = nullptr;
        vkMapMemory(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImageMemory, 0, VK_WHOLE_SIZE, 0, (void**)&data);

        MagickCore::MagickWand *wand = MagickCore::NewMagickWand();
        MagickConstituteImage(wand, swapExtent.width, swapExtent.height, "BGRA", MagickCore::CharPixel, data);

        vkUnmapMemory(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImageMemory);
        vkFreeMemory(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImageMemory, nullptr);
        vkDestroyImage(mainWindow->getRenderer()->getDevice(), dstImage, nullptr);

        MagickCore::MagickBooleanType status = MagickWriteImage(wand, filePath.c_str());

        if (!status) {
            assert(0 && "ImageMagick error: Unable to save image to file.");
        }

        MagickCore::DestroyMagickWand(wand);
        MagickCore::MagickWandTerminus();
    }
    else {
        assert(0 && "Swapchain error: Your device does not support image blitting. Cannot save image. Will be patched.");
        return;
    }

}
```